# MongoDB Zone sharding limitations - tag ranges

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

Mongo DB supports zoned sharding ([as described here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/)) by associating each shard with zone `sh.addShardTag(<shard name>, "ZONENAME")` and applying zone chunk ranges based on sharding key values with `sh.addTagRange()`.

**The questions are:**

1. Are there any limitations for `sh.addTagRange()`?
2. Does the big number of such ranges affect performance anyhow?
3. Is it OK to have for example 60000 tag ranges or they are designed to be dozens?

   Can't find the answer in docs & community forums

*to give more context on use case:*

e.g. there are 10K accounts in system. There is sharded `inventory` collection. Each item is associated with `inventoryClass` (80K types). Each account creates huge number of inventory items (SKU) by different types. There are 3 zones in sharded cluster. Shard key is: `{accountId: 1, inventoryClass: 1}`. 
Goal: to have zone distribution for particular list of accounts (home-zone defined for account manually). E.g. accounts

```
[1, 294, 906847 ...] -> zone "A", 
[7879079, 852 ...] -> zone "B",
[3457, 45...] -> zone "C"
```

Inventory item document itself doesn't containt explicit value for zone mapping (only implicit relation `accountId` -> zone mapping). It means that each `accontId` data must be associated with zone by adding corresponding tag range with `sh.addShardTag()` e.g.

```
sh.addTagRange(
  "inventory",
  { "accountId" : 1, "inventoryClass" : MinKey },
  { "accountId" : 1, "inventoryClass" : MaxKey },
  "A")
....
sh.addTagRange(
  "inventory",
  { "accountId" : 294, "inventoryClass" : MinKey },
  { "accountId" : 294, "inventoryClass" : MaxKey },
  "A")
```

so that 1 tag range per 1 account. And it results in tag ranges == accounts count

Comment: @n.prokhorove Do you check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.updateZoneKeyRange/)

Comment: @n.prokhorov - have you found the answer? I have quite similar case in work  and the same question - how big can be the number of ranges in one zone.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that having so much tag ranges will lead to increased load on Config Servers and Mongos instances. Instead, according to the [example in documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sharding-high-availability-writes/), you can include `zone` field in your documents (both `accounts` and `inventory`), and include it as prefix in your shard key. Of course, that will lead to duplication and you may need to deal with documents migration when "home zone" changes, but maybe it is not the case. Also, it is more manageable for application code to modify document's field than modifying tag ranges.